# value in the password field with out entering the value

Tags: php, html

I have a change password form. See my code

```
<dl>
<dt style="width:150px;">Old Password   </dt>
<dd><input name="frm_oldPwd" type="password"  id="frm_oldPwd" /></dd>
</dl>
<dl>
<dt style="width:150px;">New Password</dt>
<dd><input name="fem_newPwd" type="password" value="" id="fem_newPwd" /></dd>
</dl>
<dl>
<dt style="width:150px;">Confirm Password </dt>
<dd><input name="frm_cPwd" type="password" value="" id="frm_cPwd" /></dd>
</dl>
<br class="cf" />
<br />
<dl>
<dt style="width:150px;">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd><input type="submit" value="Update" name="frm_change" id="frm_changeP" /></dd>

</dl>
```

When I open this page there is a `*` symbols in the old password field. I didn't enter anything there, then how it's appearing

I have cleared my browser cookie and history etc. But still it showing

Does anyone know how I remove this?

Comment: It might be the browser's auto-fill feature.

Comment: Did you check in other browsers?

Comment: @user1263260 are you using any javascript form validation

Answer (score 1):

change it to text type to see what is the masked char:

```
<input name="frm_oldPwd" type="text"  id="frm_oldPwd" />
```

Comment: i have checked but it's nothing

Comment: @user1263260 do you mean it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute `autocomplete=off` to your password field.

Comment: what browser? maybe this is relevant: http://verysimple.com/2007/03/07/forcing-firefox-to-obey-autocompleteoff-for-password-fields/